# Graphical Demonstration of Linear Transformations on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, math-software, education

I'm looking for some applet, program, software, demonstration etc. to use it in a class while teaching linear transformation in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so that the students can graphically understand the effect of different linear transformations on the plane. I've found one as shown in the picture below:
[image]

As you can see, we can transform the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and see what happens to the purple polygon. I would be much happier if instead of a polygon, we could work with a picture and see the effect of the linear transformation on it. Do you know any such applet or program?

The students in the class are not familiar with the matrices and their product. As a matter of fact, this demonstration is intended to help them grasp the notion of matrix as a linear transformation, later in the course.

Thanks.

Comment: if you have access to mathematica, it's possible that you could use (perhaps some variant of) ImageTransformation for what you want: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageTransformation.html

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've tried ImageTransformation. There are two problems: 1. For some transformations, part of the the square which is not covered by the picture is shown black. 2. I couldn't find a way to place the coordinate axis in a proper way on the picture.

Comment: in that case, i might recommend crossposting to the mathematica stackexchange. the peeps on that forum are basically wizards

Answer (score 1):

I have an applet at http://www.math.cornell.edu/~bterrell/la It is free but is  very simple and does not handle pictures. The source code is also on my website so you can improve it if you are so inclined.

Answer (score 1):

There's this guy who does awesome videos explaining math concepts. He has a channel called 3Blue1Brown.
Here's an example video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNk_zzaMoSs&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab

On his [website](http://www.3blue1brown.com/about/), he says he uses this for animation :
https://github.com/3b1b/manim

Should interest you.